# Internet Sharing on a University Network - Will it screw things up?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I am currently running PureVPN on my University's network as I live in halls. This is running on my Mac. I wish to use the VPN on my PS4, and I have found a guide on how to do this which involved connecting my PS4 to the mac with a crossover cable and enabling Internet Sharing in my Mac's settings.

Here is the guide for PureVPN: https://www.purevpn.com/blog/ps3-vpn/

So to make this clear - my Mac is picking up WiFi, and is using PureVPN. My PS4 is connected to my Mac with a crossover cable.

However, when I go to enable internet sharing on the mac it gives me the following, somewhat chilling message -

"Are you sure you want to turn on Internet sharing? If your computer is connectd to a network, turning on Internet sharing may affect the network settings of other computers and disrupt the network. Contact your system administrator before turning on internet sharing."

What's the likelihood of things going haywire?

I'm using MacBook Pro 2015 , Yosemite.

Comment: In both cases you have to enable internet sharing.  What exactly is your question?  haywire in what regard?

Comment: I've heard that it can meddle with DHCP and reroute all computers in the network back to my PC

Comment: It won't meddle with DHCP unless you configure it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is a warning that it'll start up DHCP and/or NAT services, which, if incorrectly configured, could cause conflicts if you then wired it up to another network with DHCP and NAT running.

In this instance, you'll be enabling the sharing over an ethernet connection with only one device attached, so there shouldn't be any issue.

If, however, you had an ethernet cable connected back into the University network, well, that *might* cause some issues whilst it's running, although I can't imagine it doing anything particularly damaging or permanent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I *can* connect to the same University network through ethernet - as can others - but for this purpose I am using Wifi. If I was using Wifi and internet sharing but others on the same network were using ethernet, would there be an issue here?

Comment: @Xenidious No, not at all. My last example was if you were using the WiFi, but trying to share the internet *back* into their ethernet. That may cause issues. What you're trying to do, ethernet directly into a PS4, won't cause a problem. (Whether it'll work I don't know, but it won't hurt to try).

Comment: Ok. And just making sure - there is definitely no way for anyone else to connect to my PC? (The only device being able to do that being the PS4?)

Comment: @Xenidious - If you share the internet to your ethernet port, only devices on your ethernet port will be able to connect to it. Purely using this example (Uni -> WiFi -> Mac -> Ethernet (W/Internet Sharing) -> PS4) you won't be setting up a server to the entire university, just your PS4.

Comment: How is a third-party device going to connect to your PC, if it requires a physical cable to do so, you are only going to share the internet with devices you configure.

Comment: I'm using a crossover cable. I'm running PureVPN on the PC, which I share to my ethernet. This ethernet is connected to the PS4. So its not my internet connection thats being shared its the PureVPN connection

Comment: @Jonno I'm running into issues here - wondering if you can help (but its ok if you cant!) I have set my ethernet's IPv4 manually using the following: IP Address 192.168.25.1 and Subnet 255.255.255.0. It now says it is connected to the internet. So I've connected the other end to the ps4 and gone into the network settings. On the PS4 I have set the following: IP: 192.168.25.2
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.25.1.   However when it tries to connect it says that DNS have not been set. I can set these to something specific - but I'm not sure what they should be.

Comment: @Xenidious try using a public DNS like Google's, 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

Comment: Yea i've tried this and OpenDNS but no luck unfortunately